# No Icons after Fontawesome upgrade in ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, font-awesome-5

I have Sencha ExtJS 6 and some of new FontAwesome icons didn't work out. I thought it is due to old version of FontAwesome. Then I decided to upgrade it and I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/yamayamayamaji/extjs-package-fontawesome
which says:

> Replace your /ext(framework_dir)/packages/font-awesome/
>   with /font-awesome/
>
> then run sencha app refresh

But after this I cannot see any of FontAwesome icons.

So this:

```
{
    title: 'Dashboard',
    iconCls: 'fa-home',
    bind:
    {
        html: 'Test'
    }

},
```

now looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Btw I don't have any errors in Console.

Comment: Was it an upgrade form 4 to 5? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025192/upgrade-process-for-fontawesome-from-4-to-5

Comment: Yes. But could not find any other tutorial for ExtJS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fontCls` parameter is missing.

In ExtJS 6, `iconCls` is specified with the following notation:

```
iconCls: '{fontCls} {iconPrefix}-{iconName}'
```

So, rather than just `fa-home`, try specifying `x-fa fa-home`, as below:

```
iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home'
```

[image: Available ExtJS Font Packages]

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/font_ext.html